# Plotly scatter matrix with color showing density

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot

Is it possible to do a [scatter matrix plot with Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/splom/) in which the color shows the density like this (not Plotly)?

[image]

I would like to have the functionality of the `px.scatter_matrix` function, i.e. that the axes are shared, and also a similar interface if possible. I cannot find such thing.

If it is not a scatter plot with individual points but a collection of 2D histograms that would also work.

Comment: Even in your example, it looks like someone superimposed a heatmap (using kde or something), which you can do in plotly. If you truly want a scatter plot with marker color corresponding to some scale then you can't really do that. Plotly doesn't (yet, maybe someday) accept a vector of colors.